Help identifying a book
I saw a RPG campaign book at a game store while traveling. I don't remember the title. On the cover there were 4 adventurers, of elven appearance, delving in either a dungeon or a cavern. One of the adventurers was in some sort of magical wheel chair. I think the title had the word Enchiridion in it. The cover of the book was dark blue or purple. The publisher logo on the back was yellow if I remember correctly. It was advertised as a 50 hour campaign.

Could you remember, what game/edition it was?

Might also be useful to say how long ago this was, recently or a decade ago?

It was two weeks ago. No idea on the game or edition. I think there may have been a logo on the back that had the word beneath or underneath on it. It was priced at $29.99.

Where where you? What city/town, state? Name of the shop?  Enchiridion is bringing  back memories of Adventure Time for me. :)
